# Python check if there's any empty string in multiple strings

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I know it's a basic question but please bear with me. Let's say if we have 4 strings below:

```
a = ''
b = 'apple'
c = 'orange'
d = 'banana'
```

So, normally if I want to check if any of the three string `a` `b` `c` is empty, I could use `len()` function.

```
if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0 or len(c) == 0:
    return True
```

But then I thought it is too troublesome to write like above if I have many strings. So, I used

```
if not a:
    return True
```

But, when i am checking for multiple strings `b` `c` `d` using the above method, it returns `True` and I am puzzled as non of the strings `b` `c` `d` where empty.

```
if not b or c or d:
    return True
```

What is going on?

Comment: care to explain the reason for downvote?

Comment: I suspect you may be expecting too much of the `or` operator. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah. It's not quite clear whether this is a precedence confusion, a misunderstanding of what `or` really does, or something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies with this line:

```
if not b or c or d:
```

You need to include the "not" condition for each string.  So:

```
if not b or not c or not d:
```

You could also do it like this:

```
    return '' in [a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 3):

The not operator has higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than or.

```
return not b or not c or not d
```

should work.